# Question with transcribing English to Predicate Logic & find assertion which is logically equivalent.

Tags: predicate-logic

Anyone knows how to solve the question 10(especially 10(b)) & 11?

I actually have the standard/model answers, but I don't really know how they understand the question and solve it step by step.

Anyone can explain it and help me out....I am in trouble...

I have answers already...I just want the detailed explanation.

[Question 10 & 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Titj9.png)

[Standard/Model Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKLLx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ($10$b), I would cast it as:
$$\forall x\forall y\,{\big[}P(x,x,y) \rightarrow \bigl(G(y,0)\lor E(y,0)\bigr){\big ]}$$

The thought process:

> $y = x^2\;$can't happen unless $y \ge 0$.
>
> Hence, if $y=x^2$, we must have $y \ge 0$.
>
> Using if-then:$\;$If $y=x^2$, then $y \ge 0$.
>
> Converting to symbols:$\;P(x,x,y) \rightarrow \bigl(G(y,0) \lor E(y,0)\bigr)$.
>
> Finally, quantify the variables $x,y:\;\forall x \forall y\,{\big[}P(x,x,y) \rightarrow \bigl(G(y,0)\lor E(y,0)\bigr){\big ]}$.

@Fabio Somenzi answered problem ($11$).

Comment: I edited it with posting the model answer......regarding to your answer, it's correct..logically...so thanks, but why would the model answer of 10(b) comes with 3 steps, do you know how they figure out?? Any why they put the quantifier in front and why you don't?...........so confusing..

Comment: I think they'e trying to transform the word version, one small piece at a time. I see that as more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Can I also solve the problem like this?? ∀y[∀xP(x,x,y)→(G(y,0)∨E(y,0)]

Comment: As far as missing quantifiers, I've edited them in. They should be there. In an informal context, for symbols that are viewed as variables (non-constants), the universal quantifiers can be regarded as implied.

Comment: Yes, the version in your previous comment is essentially the same.

Comment: Just one more question, for the standard/model answer of 10(b), there are 3 step as indicated in there. How would you explain the step 1?? You answer is much more clear, but I still want to know how the step 1 comes out...

Comment: In words, step $1$ says: For all integers $y$, there is no integer $x$ such that $y=x^2$ _and_ $y$ is not  greater or equal to zero. But such steps are not cast in stone, so I wouldn't take those exact steps too seriously (unless the teacher requires it).

Comment: Thanks bro...it helps a lot on my university study!! Math professor doesn't teach well...every student agrees on a thing..."That professor sucks"

lol.....Anyway, you absolutely deserve that "Best Answer" :D (I wanna share the joy with the another answerer "Fabio Somenzi" but the system doesn't allow....what a shame :p)

Answer (score 0):

For Problem 11, you want to express that there is a unique $x$ that satisfies $P$.  It can be done as follows:

$$ \exists x(P(x) \wedge \forall y (P(y) \rightarrow Q(x,y))) \enspace.$$

It says that there is an $x$ that satisfies $P$, and for all $y$, if they satisfy $P$, they must be equal to $x$.

@quasi answered 10(b)